# Emscripten can't find clang

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, clang, emscripten

I installed Emscripten from the site (See https://emscripten.org/), followed the steps, however when I try run it with `emcc ./Desktop/cpp/test.cpp -o test.html`, it gives me the error "emcc: error: '/home/kit/emsdk/upstream/bin/clang --version' failed: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/kit/emsdk/upstream/bin/clang'" I've checked in this directory, the clang executable is there.
I tried running `/home/kit/emsdk/upstream/bin/clang` in the terminal, however bash says the file cannot be found. I am using a raspberry pi 400. Can anyone explain why this is, and any possible fixes? Thanks.

Comment: What does `ls -l /home/kit/emsdk/upstream/bin/clang` produce? is it a symlink to a file that indeed does not exist?

Comment: @Botje `ls -l /home/kit/emsdk/upstream/bin/clang` produces `lrwxrwxrwx 1 kit kit 8 Oct 10 22:31 /home/kit/emsdk/upstream/bin/clang -> clang-18`. This is strange, as I'm pretty sure executables start with a '-', not an 'l'

Comment: Yes, so it's a symlink. Now, does `/home/kit/emsdk/upstream/bin/clang-18` exist? If not, there's your problem.

Comment: @Botje `/home/kit/emsdk/upstream/bin/clang-18` indeed does exist